# Implicit function $y = e^{(y-1)/x}$

Tags: special-functions, functional-equations

I'd like to know if the function $ y = f(x) : [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ defined implicitly by the transcendental equation $$\displaystyle y = e^{(y-1)/x}$$ is "well known" (name, properties) or is related to some other well known function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is solvable employing the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) as follows.

Your equation is $\rm\quad\quad\ Y \ \: =\ e^{\:Z-YZ}\ \: $ for $\rm\: \ Z\ =\: -\frac{1}X$

$\rm\quad\quad\iff\ \ Y\:Z\ e^{Y\:Z}\ \:=\:\ Z\ e^Z$

$\rm\quad\quad\iff\ \  Y\:Z\ \ \:=\:\ \ W(Z\ e^Z) $

$\rm\quad\quad\iff\ \ Y\: =\: -X\ W(-\frac{1}X e^{-1/X}) $

Answer (score 5):

To give a more detailed solution, we start by rearranging the original equation as

$$y\exp\left(\frac{1-y}{x}\right)=1$$

and then

$$y\exp\left(\frac1{x}\right)\exp\left(-\frac{y}{x}\right)=1$$

$$-y\exp\left(-\frac{y}{x}\right)=-\exp\left(-\frac1{x}\right)$$

$$-\frac{y}{x}\exp\left(-\frac{y}{x}\right)=-\frac1{x}\exp\left(-\frac1{x}\right)$$

which we can now invert to

$$-\frac{y}{x}=W\left(-\frac1{x}\exp\left(-\frac1{x}\right)\right)$$

and finally we have

$$y=-xW\left(-\frac1{x}\exp\left(-\frac1{x}\right)\right)$$

Though the Lambert function has *two* real branches, only the "principal branch" gives a nontrivial solution; the solution corresponding to the $W_{-1}(\cdot)$ branch is $y=1$